# Reading file gives more lines

Tags: java

I have a text file with 201288 lines:

```
$ wc -l text_in.txt 
201288 text_in.txt
```

I want to read that file line by line, remove all non alphanumeric characters and print every line in a new file. After having done that, I noticed that the new file has more lines. I tried two things and both gave me different results:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileOut);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileIn));
String s;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    out.println(s);
    out.flush();
}

$ wc -l text_out.txt 
201995 text_out.txt
```

And:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileIn))) {
    stream.forEach(line -> out.println(line));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

$ wc -l text_out.txt 
201932 text_out.txt
```

What seems to be the correct way to do this?

Comment: According to it's documentation, "wc -l" counts newline characters, but "br.readLine()" has three differen newline delimiters: \r, \n and \r\n. Do you have any \r in your file that are not immediately followed by a \n character? That might explain the difference...

Comment: `wc -l` only counts new lines ('\n'), java recognizes more line terminators ("\r\n", '\r', '\n' https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to line encoding.

`wc -l` on Unix / Linux will only match a newline if it's a linux-style line end (`LF`). Java's [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) will match any possible line ending (`CR`, `LF`, `CR LF`), and [`PrintWriter.println(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println--) will print it out in platform's default line encoding (`LF` in your case), which will then be counted by `wc -l` on next run.